# Explain the Equality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading a [proof](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~bhiksha/courses/deeplearning/Fall.2016/pdfs/Cybenko.pdf) by G. Cybenko, and I'm stuck on one step as follows:
Let $F$ be a linear form satisfying $F(h)=\int_{I_{n}}h(y^Tx)\,d\mu(x)$, where $y$ is fixed, $\mu$ is some regular Borel measure, $h$ is a bounded measurable function, and $I_{n}$ is the n-dimensional unit cube, $[0,1]^n$.
Let $s(u)=\sin(m*u)$ and $c(u)=\cos(m*u)$.

Why does $F(s+ic)=\int_{I_{n}}\cos(m^Tx)+i\sin(m^Tx)\,d\mu(x)$?
I feel like this is a trivial hang-up.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, $F$ is linear...

Comment: But by linearity I would have thought $F(s+ic)=\int_{I_{n}}\sin(m^Tx)+i\cos(m^Tx)\,d\mu(x)$ if anything.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that the $\sin$ and $\cos$ are switched. So I guess there is a typo in the paper and it should have been $F(c + is)$.

Comment: I was thinking this but in searching around I see many people's reformulations of this proof have the same "typo" included:  
http://mcneela.github.io/machine_learning/2017/03/21/Universal-Approximation-Theorem.html and http://hananel.hazan.org.il/files/Advance%20Seminar%20on%20Neuro-Computation/2010/nn1.pdf

Comment: Both links copied the paper by Cybenko almost verbatim, so it wouldn't surprise me if they also blindly copied this apparent typo.

Comment: For the sake of my sanity let's hope so. Thanks Nigel.

Comment: What is $m$? Vector? Scalar?

Comment: It seems $m$ is a scalar and I've assumed $m^T:=my^T$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the author has made a typo, where he meant to write
 $F(c+is)=\int_{I_{n}}\cos(m^Tx)+i\sin(m^Tx)\,d\mu(x)$.